# For a set $E$ of finite Lebesgue measure, $\lim_{y \to 0} m((E + y) - E) = 0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I am having some trouble proving the following:

> Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ have finite measure. Then  $\lim_{y \to 0} m((E + y) - E) = 0$

**Context:** I am studying the Fourier transform, and I am trying to prove the following lemma:

> Suppose that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\lim_{y \to 0}||f(x-y) - f(x)||_p = 0.$

My plan is to prove it for simple functions first, and then use their density in $L^p$ to prove it for all functions. But to prove it for simple functions, I have to prove that $\lim_{y \to 0} m((E + y) - E) = 0$, which I am having trouble with.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: By the regularity theorem, for $\epsilon > 0$ there are closed and open sets $F \subseteq E \subseteq U$ such that $m(U - F) < \epsilon$.  Then $$(E+y) - E \subseteq (U+y) - E \subseteq (U+y) - F.$$
So it suffices to show this last set's measure tends to $0$ as $y \to 0$.  I'm not sure if this makes the problem easier.

Comment: If you take a seq $y_n \to 0$ then intersection of all of $E+y_n$ is the empty set. So the measure of $E+y_n$ must tend to zero.

Comment: Regarding the actual problem in fourier analysis, you can actually prove it for continuous compactly supported functions first; these are also dense in $L^p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the approximation thorem of measure theory: Theorem D, p. 56 of Halmos' Measure Theory,  to reduce this to the case when $E=(a,b]$.

Comment: I do not have this book, but I think I know what type of theorem you are referring to. Thank you, I will give it a try.